# asp.net web api call custom method using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-dropdown

i have a angularJS controller where i put a kendo cascade dropdownlist.For dropdown list value ,on kendo dataSource read i am calling the web api service.
For the first field the api GetDivisions() has been called and it response also but for the 2nd value the GetCascadeDistrict() method not called the GetDivisions() method called again. How can i solve this.Need Help

here's the angular Controller with kendo cascade dropdownlist.

```
app.controller("filterCtrl", function($scope, $sce,$http) {
var i;
$scope.dashImgSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('Content/Images/Bangladesh_Govt.gif');

$(document).ready(function () {

    var divisions = $("#divisions").kendoComboBox({
        filter: "contains",
        placeholder: "select a divisions...",
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        animation: {
          close: {
              effects: "zoom:out",
              durations:250
          }  
        },
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: "api/AreaService/GetDivisions()"
            }
        },
        change: function () {
            i = divisions.value();
            alert("1st hit"+i);
        }
    }).data("kendoComboBox");


    var districts = $("#districts").kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "divisions",
        filter: "contains",
        placeholder: "select a district",
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: function () {

                    alert("2nd hit");

                    //$http.get("/api/AreaService/GetCascadeDistrict(i)").success(function() {
                    //    alert("Hit the district api");
                    //}).error(function() {
                    //    alert("Error");
                    //});

                    $http({ method: "GET", url: 'api/AreaService/GetCascadeDistrict(i)' }).
                        success(function() {
                            alert("Actually it hit the custome get method");
                        }).
                        error(function() {
                            alert("Not hit or other problem");
                        });


                }
            }
        }


    }).data("kendoComboBox");


    var upazila = $("#upazila").kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "districts",
        filter: "contains",
        placeholder: "select a  upazila...",
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: function() {
                    $http.get("/api/AreaService/GetCascadeDistrict(i)").success(function() {

                    }).error(function() {

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }).data("kendoComboBox");

    $("#get").click(function () {
        var divisionInfo = "\Division: { id: " + divisions.value() + ", name: " + divisions.text() + " }",
            districtInfo = "\nDistrict: { id: " + districts.value() + ", name: " + districts.text() + " }",
            upazilaInfo = "\nUpazila: { id: " + upazila.value() + ", name: " + upazila.text() + " }";

        alert("Road details:\n" + divisionInfo + districtInfo + upazilaInfo);
    });
});
```

});

And the Web api is here

```
public class AreaServiceController : ApiController
{
    private readonly AreaFilterManager _db = new AreaFilterManager();

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Division> GetDivisions()
    {
        return _db.GetDivisions();
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<District> GetCascadeDistrict(int? division)
    {
        return _db.GetCascadeDistrict(division);
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Thana> GetCascadeUpzilla(int? district)
    {
        return _db.GetCascadeThana(district);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to separate/distinguish your calls by **[CRUD](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)** operations or by **[Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)** depends your `WebApi` version your using in your project.

You cannot use the same **[CRUD](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)** `HttpGet` twice in the same Class/Controller without putting a different routing attribute.

You need to remember, in `WebApi` the methods are not being called by their names like in regular programming, therefore the `WebApi` Class/Controller doesn't know which method you meant to call from your Client (in your case).

That's why you'll need to:

`WebApi` Ver 1 : separate/distinguish your calls by **[CRUD](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)** operations.

`WebApi` Ver 2 : separate/distinguish your calls by **[Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)**.

Comment: Thanks for your  valuable information. Actually i am new in developing. Can you tell me little bit more in details  how can i separate calls by [CRUD][1] or [Attribute Routing].

Comment: I updated the Answer above, please check now to see whether you understand more now.